# XML -> XSLT -> DB

Tags: .net, xml

I have a series of XML documents that I need to process, storing key elements and attributes in a couple of relational tables (a 'one' and a related 'many' table).

I have determined the correct Xpath logic needed to identify the relevant nodes.

One approach would be to process the DOM node sets when the transformation completes, inserting records as appropriate.  While this will work, it seems pretty inelegant.

Another optional would be to generate a CSV file, then bulk insert it.

In either case, it would be nice to have a flexible means to map an XPath to a table/column combination in a settings file, rather than hard-code it.

Are there any particularly-elegant ways to handle this situation that I'm not considering?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how can fit this question XSLT if you want to parse an XML and insert the records in db.

Comment: Essentially, to transform a verbose XML document into 1) another format like CSV or 2) one that could be more-easily mapped to a db table.

Comment: Right but bear in mind that this will bring an additional step who, in my opinion, can be avoid.

Comment: What about creating ORM mapping by Entity FW (or some other), than create instances of entity classes and transform XML data by Linq to XML to entity classes and that save it by entity data context?

Comment: @Aurelio, how would you approach this problem?  'Walk' the DOM, inserting as you go?

Comment: @Michal, that sounds like an interesting approach.  Do you have some code you could share?

Answer (score 0):

Since I had the same problem, I'll tell you how I dealt with. I created the DOM based on my XML file. To ensure that it was no error in my sql statements, I had not insert the data "on the fly" but I created a file where it was the `INSERT` statements. To optimize the insert I create a `INSERT` statement every 50 `VALUES(...)`. After I've checked that was all right, I inserted my rows in the database.

I hope this little walkthrough can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. Is your database a SQL server database?  If so you might want to look at OpenXML, which allows you to query the xml directly and insert the data into tables.  Essentially your .net app would have no smarts, all it would do is read the xml contents and pass them as a parameter to a sql statement.